# Oracle Group By Month, Year, Order by Year, Month

Tags: oracle, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm trying to write a query in Oracle that'll group a date by month and year, and then order these neatly.
Besides this the month has to have it's name displayed rather than it's month number.

The query I currently have is:

```
SELECT to_char(datumgeleend, 'MONTH') as "Maand geleend", 
to_char(datumgeleend, 'YYYY') as "Jaar geleend", SUM(bedrag)
FROM lening
GROUP BY to_char(datumgeleend, 'MONTH'), to_char(datumgeleend, 'YYYY')
ORDER BY to_char(datumgeleend, 'YYYY'), to_char(datumgeleend, 'MONTH') DESC;
```

Problem is that the order by works on the first letter of the month rather than the number of the month.

So I thought to fix that I'd adjust the query slightly to:

```
SELECT to_char(datumgeleend, 'MONTH') as "Maand geleend", 
to_char(datumgeleend, 'YYYY') as "Jaar geleend", SUM(bedrag)
FROM lening
GROUP BY to_char(datumgeleend, 'MONTH'), to_char(datumgeleend, 'YYYY')
ORDER BY to_char(datumgeleend, 'YYYY'), extract(month from datumgeleend) 
DESC;
```

Sadly this query generates the following error:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `extract(month from datumgeleend)` to the group by clause:

```
SELECT to_char(datumgeleend, 'MONTH') as "Maand geleend", 
to_char(datumgeleend, 'YYYY') as "Jaar geleend", SUM(bedrag)
FROM lening
GROUP BY to_char(datumgeleend, 'MONTH'), to_char(datumgeleend, 'YYYY'), extract(month from datumgeleend)
ORDER BY to_char(datumgeleend, 'YYYY'), extract(month from datumgeleend) DESC;
```

Comment: Ah yes that does the job perfectly! I did not realize it'd have to be put in the GROUP BY as well. In the end I had to take away the DESC to make it sort correctly but that had nothing to do with the question :) Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround, using the WITH factoring clause, additional column (which has to be included into the GROUP BY clause) used to sort data as you want it):

```
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT
    TO_CHAR(datumgeleend,'MONTH') AS maand_geleend,
    TO_CHAR(datumgeleend,'YYYY') AS jaar_geleend,
    SUM(bedrag) sum_bedrag,
   --
    TO_CHAR(datumgeleend,'yyyymm') yyyymm
  FROM
    lening
  GROUP BY
    TO_CHAR(datumgeleend,'MONTH'),
    TO_CHAR(datumgeleend,'YYYY'),
    TO_CHAR(datumgeleend,'yyyymm')
) SELECT
  maand_geleend,
  jaar_geleend,
  sum_bedrag
  FROM
  temp
ORDER BY
  yyyymm DESC;
```

Comment: Ooh thanks for the workaround, good to know that that is possible :D The other solution though was simpler so I chose that as the answer to make it easier for others with similar problems!

Thank you for your answer!